# Downloading my new program on chrome dangerous?

Tags: .net, google-chrome

On my website birdseyeviewtech.com I have created a download link to Amazon S3 Web Services that hosts my program Birds Eye View Optimization Tool.

When my tool is downloaded on chrome it says "Birds Eye View Optimization Tool.exe is not commonly downloaded and may be dangerous."

The previous version of my program didn't have this error after waiting for a couple of days.

Does this mean Chrome will give this error every time I upload a new version of my program? Is there any way I should be updating my program to avoid this? Or any way I should be uploading my file on Amazon Web Services S3 bucket to avoid this from happening again on a later version?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

Google Safe Browsing analyses executables and will mark them as safe, but this generally doesn't happen until the executable has been downloaded a few times (hence your problem). This isn't linked to S3, and if your file is safe, the warning should disappear. This error will occur wherever you move your executable to.

Unfortunately, you can't request a review because you don't own the S3 domains but it should disappear within a few days.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/3258249?hl=en (down bottom)
https://transparencyreport.google.com/safe-browsing/overview